# Help proving that two topologies generated by two different metrics are the same

Tags: general-topology

Let $d_2$ and $d_{\infty}$ be metrics on $\mathbb{R^3}$.
Hence:

$$d_2((x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2))=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}$$
$$d_{\infty}((x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2))=max(|x_1-x_2|,|y_1-y_2)|,|z_1-z_2|)$$

So i need to prove that the toplogies: $\mathcal{T}_2 ,\mathcal{T}_{\infty}$ are the same(both are generated by the obvious metric).
So since i have to prove they are the same, it means that  they have the same base.
They are generated by metric so their base is an open ball.
So if they are the same, both metrices have to have identical open balls.

AM i on the right track, or am i wrong?

Comment: No, they don't have to have the same open balls. Rather, show that for each metric, an open ball in that metric is still an open _set_ in the other.

Comment: Generally saying, these metrics are generated by norms $\|\cdot\|_2$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$. In finite dimensional space all the norms are equivalent, which means they generate the same topology.

Comment: They don't have the same open balls. They have the same open $sets$........ Show that every open $d_2$-ball is a union of open $d_{\infty}$ balls and vice-versa.......   It suffices to show that when  $p\in \Bbb R^3$ and $r>0$   there exists $s>0$ such that $B_{d_{\infty}}(p,s)\subset B_{d_2}(p,r)$, and vice-versa.......  An open $d_2$-ball $B$ about $p$ is spherical, and contains  an open cubical region   $C$ centered at $p,$ which is an open $d_{\infty}$-ball. And $C$ contains an open spherical region $D$ centered at $p$, which is an open $d_2$-ball.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be open in $d_2$. Let $(x_1,x_2,x_3):=x \in U$, then there exists some open ball $(B,r)$ that contains $x$ and is properly contained in $U$. But as soon as this happens, we also have that there is a neighborhood $B_\infty$ given by $max(|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|,|x_3-y_3|)<r$.

This can be seen since $|(x_i-y_i)| <r$, since the sum of their squares is less than $r^2$. But then $B_\infty) \subset (B,r) \subset U$. Hence, $U$ is open in $d_\infty$ as well, and the other direction is similar